# Directory.Exists not working for a network path

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I have a line of code checking if a directory exists and then getting the list of files in it.

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"\\Server\Folder\");
```

I works when I test it (run from visual studio), but when I deploy the web site, it always returns false.

I do the same verification for another folder, on another server (let's say Server2) and it works fine.

I then thought it was an access issue, but the shared folder and network have all access to everyone... Is there another reason why it would not work?

Comment: Does the account that IIS runs under have access?

Comment: Is it not able to de-reference `Server`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you run the code in Visual Studio it runs under the the rights of your user.

When you run the code in IIS it runs in the identity of the Application Pool which by default is the built in user "Network Service" this is a local user account which does not have access outside the local machine.

The rights on the network share are the first layer, after that the NTFS rights on the directory are checked.

You need to change the identity of the application pool to a domain user with the same rights as your user.

Comment: It worked on my local IIS for tests too, but the setting were to Application user, so it was taking my local windows user to connect to the network. I set my specific user to the official server's IIS and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a user with rights to all the source and destination directories I need to copy files from and to. Is there any other way to connect to the drives? It also doesn't work with mapped network drives by using the drive letters, so doing a "net use" will also not help I guess.

Comment: Thanks so much. Spent half a day with this headache.

Answer (score 6):

I may be a little late, but i've found that there is a problem on this method of the `Directory` class.
Instead i've used `DirectoryInfo` with impersonation this way:

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).Exists
```

This way you avoid the whole identity change problem, which was denied by our IT area.

I hope this helps somebody!

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue of impersonation. The main difference is that `Directory` is a static class and `DirectoryInfo` is an instance of a class.

Comment: I'll try this.  We are getting intermittant failures with a share from a server between the US and Ireland.  There is no indication of server trouble.   My guess there is a timeout as this server is at times slow to respond.

Answer (score 3):

For future references, this also works:

```
bool result = false;
try
{
    Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
    result = true;
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    result = true;
}
catch
{
    result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was was getting this error with code a UNC that looked like this:

@"\Server01\c$\Data\SubFolder"

I made an explicit share and got rid of the `c$` and made it look like this:

@"\Server01\TheData\SubFolder"

and it started to work.

I am not 100% sure that is what fixed the permissions problem, but it started to work immediately after making that change.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out for me all I had to do when I was adding the network drive was to run the `net use ...` command from an elevated command prompt. My application runs as administrator so I'm guessing that's probably why it worked after that.

`net use G: \\<NETWORK_DRIVE_NAME>\<FOLDER_NAME>  /u:<USER> <PASSWORD> /persistent:yes`

[More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/cannot-copy-files-from-mapped-drive-to-local-directory)

Answer (score 0):

When i got into the same error, what i did was

1. Application pool identity changed to custom user with domain user credentials.
2. Added a virtual directory path to the IIS Website with that network path.

[Adding a virtual path to the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a70cH.png)

[Managing the network path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqpqJ.png)

[Last result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq42G.png)