# Using DirectoryInfo.Exists is false even if the directory exists

Tags: c#, directory, directoryinfo

I'm having a problem when creating a DirectoryInfo, The directory I give when creating the DirectoryInfo is this:

> "S:\PUBLICO\ESTUDIOS
>   DIGITALIZADOS\PREVENTIVA\ELECTROS\2020\01-ENERO\08\"

And when checking if DirectoryInfo exists it's false, even though it exists. This is a problem because it throws an exception even when using di.GetFiles().

Also, when accessing folders from 2019 instead of 2020 it works perfectly, and uses the exact same code
[image: As you can see, the directory exists]

This is the code that matters:

```
strDirectorioBase = strDirectorioECG + "\\" + Anio + "\\" + Mes + "-" + NombreMes + "\\" + Dia + "\\";

        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(strDirectorioBase);
            /*FileInfo[] a = di.GetFiles(strFiltro, SearchOption.AllDirectories);*/
            MessageBox.Show(di.Exists.ToString());
            if (di.Exists)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Existe");
            }
            foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles(strFiltro, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Directory.Exists not working for a network path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196811/directory-exists-not-working-for-a-network-path)

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: I dont think so, because it's a local server folder to which every user has full access

Comment: The exception is DirectoryNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the folder GetFiles will not continue past exception.  You need to use recursive code like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```